# Random Xcode error that I don't understand

Tags: xcode, swift

So i'm getting this error that says EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION and I have no idea why can anyone shed any light on it?? the code in question in bold below. Just so you know this is using SWIFT

```
**actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alien.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))**

    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

    alien.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
```

Here is a longer view of the code for you

alien.position = CGPointMake(position, self.frame.size.height+alien.size.height)

```
    self.addChild(alien)

    let minDuration = 2
    let maxDuration = 4
    let rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration
    let duration = Int(arc4random()) % Int(rangeDuration) + Int(minDuration)

    var actionArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(position, -alien.size.height), duration: NSTimeInterval(duration)))

    actionArray.addObject(SKAction.removeFromParent())

    alien.runAction(SKAction.sequence(actionArray))
```

Comment: How is `actionArray` defined?

Comment: It would also help to know how `position` is defined

Comment: I have sprite.position = location and i have         player.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, player.size.height/2 + 20)

Comment: But you are using a variable that is just `position` in the line that is crashing.

Comment: this is what i have for position           let position:CGFloat = CGFloat(arc4random()) % CGFloat(rangeX) + CGFloat(minX)

Comment: An EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION implies that there is an assert happening. I thought there would be an optional somewhere that was `nil` but that does not appear to be possible from the code you provided. I recommend you look at the call stack and try to figure out where the assert is really happening and why.

Comment: So randomly it seems to work if i change the iOS simulator "/ I'm thinking now maybe it's a bug in the Xcode Beta!

Comment: Interesting, ya I would submit a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Answer (score 1):

Is your Xcode updated to beta 4 ? 
Also try going to Window -> Organizer -> select your project -> choose delete next to 'Derived Data'. 
I had a weird bug where my app would only run in the simulator, and give me the EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error if I used my device. Deleting the Derived Data fixed it.